# How to get Owner's Contact Info from "Me" Profile Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I succeed to get the Display/Full Name of Owner. But I want to get the owner's phone number and profile picture. I mean, when we go to contacts, there is a profile named "ME", I want to get those information. How can I? It will be good to have a brief explanation with code. (Thanks)

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv_contact_name);
            number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv_contact_number);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);

            Cursor c = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

  name.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            }

            c.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special method to construct a `ProfileUri`, try this:

```
// profile uri
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Profile.CONTENT_URI, Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
// cursor with all the data on that uri
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
// dump the cursor
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);
cur.close();
```